# Constructing an array for Google Forms .createResponse in a GRID item type when null values are present and needed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am getting values from a sheet and needing to convert the values into an array that will then be accepted by .createResponse() of Google Forms for a GRID item type. In the spreadsheet, the values for cell[0] = NYC, cell[1] = LA, and cell[2] = Dallas. The following function will work when there is data in each of the cells.  However, if one of the cells is blank, then the function converts the blank entries into null.  I am using this same technique of converting blanks to null for CHECKBOX_GRID items in other functions and this same technique has been stated as the solution for getting GRID items to be formatted correctly.  However, the function errors out at the var itemResponse line with the error of "Exception: Invalid response submitted to grid question."  I know that this means the data in the response array does not match the possible choices in the GRID item type.  Anyone know why this function is not working properly?

```
function stackExp(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
  var countMC = form.getItems()[0].asGridItem().getRows().length;
  var arr = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheetName).getRange(4, 2, 1, countMC).getValues()[0].map(e => e.trim());

  for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    if(arr[j] == '' || arr[j] == ""){
      arr[j] = null;
    }
  }
  
  var itemResponse = form.getItems()[0].asGridItem().createResponse(arr); //Errors here
  form.createResponse().withItemResponse(itemResponse).submit();
}
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue (form or sheet). Please share it so we can see how you are going about implementing this. That way it would be easier to understand why you are getting this error.

Comment: Sorry about that.  formCreate is form.createResponse().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have a Google Form including a GridItem to the 1st item.
- The GridItem has 3 rows `Pizza,Burgers,Tacos` and 4 columns which are `Chicago,NY,LA,Dallas` in order.
- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "B4:D4" of `dataSheetName` sheet, and want to use the values as the response of this item.

#### Issue:

- For example, when this form item is manually submitted including an unchecked button using a script, `["NY", null, "Chicago"]` is obtained. But, when `["NY", null, "Chicago"]` is used to the submitted value using a script, an error like `Exception: Invalid response submitted to grid question.`.

  - This situation has already been reported as a bug to the Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195036484)
- On March 16, 2022 (yesterday), Google Forms API has released as the alpha version. But in the current stage, the form response cannot be submitted using Forms API. I thought that this method might be able to be added in the future update.

#### Workaround:

In the current workaround for achieving your goal, I would like to propose the following workaround. In this workaround, the values are directly submitted to the Form using UrlFetchApp.

```js
function sample() {
  const ids = ["entry.###", "entry.###", "entry.###"]; // Please set each entry ID.
  var dataSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
  const countMC = form.getItems()[0].asGridItem().getRows().length;
  const arr = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheetName).getRange(4, 2, 1, countMC).getValues()[0].map((e, i) => e ? `${ids[i]}=${e.trim()}` : null).filter(e => e);
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/${form.getId()}/formResponse`;
  const endpoint = `${url}?${arr.join("&")}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, { method: "post" });
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

In order to retrieve `const ids = ["entry.###", "entry.###", "entry.###"];`, you can use the following script. Before you use this script, please submit the Form by 3 checked button. By this, 3 entry IDs can be retrieved.

```
    function sample2() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
      const prefilledUrl = form.getResponses().pop().toPrefilledUrl();
      console.log(prefilledUrl)
    }
```

#### References:

- [Class GridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Directly Submitting Answers to Google Form using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/09/27/directly-submitting-answers-to-google-form-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: The GRID item is actually a 3 row, 3 column Multiple Choice Grid that does not require the user to have a value entered in each row.  When there is not a value selected, then null is supposed to be used in the array to signify this.  You can see the structure of the question here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeh-SoeKyupvSCj1iljkCmLV5x_EofkeJWDONRGekmrX90ePA/viewform

Comment: Sorry.  It's late and I'm tired.  Yes - 3x4.  The problem is that the Google documentation states that null must be included in the array when there is no value.  When I geValues from the row, the correct cells is collected.  An array of ['Chicago','NY','LA'] works properly.  If you delete a cell and get something like ['','NY','LA'], this will throw an error.  The documentation states that '' must be replaced with null (which works correctly with CHECKBOX_GRID items).  If I then use [null,'NY','LA'], then the error is given.

Comment: I did try filtering out the "" values but that causes the error of: Exception: Wrong number of responses: 2. Expected exactly: 3. - which is due to the null value not being accounted for in the array.

Comment: @ADOrch Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In the current stage, it seems that your issue is a bug. So, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I was hoping that I was doing something wrong and that it wasn't a bug.  It also looks like Google isn't working on this very quickly.  Thanks for the Pre-Filled URL workaround.  I'll see if I can work that into my project.  Thank you for your help.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @ADOrch Thank you for replying. I would like to believe that this bug is resolved in the future update.

Comment: The bug has finally been resolved by Google.